# What's the way to update object in React state without initial properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

I have a problem with updating object in a React state, when I can't set initial properties.

In initial state I have an empty object

Then I have a function to handle checkbox changes

I'm generating fields with checkboxes after API response, so I can't set them in initial state, because of number or id changes. What's the way to handle this? When I'm trying to check checkbox there's only one property in object.

This is my component:

```
const Emails = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState({});

    const { eventId } = useParams();

    const handleCheckboxes = (event) => {
        setCheckedItems({
            ...checkedItems,
            [event.target.id]: event.target.checked
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchEmails();
    }, [])

    const fetchEmails = async () => {
        try {
            const resp = await axios.get(`${url}/${eventId}`);
            const newRows = resp.data.map(row => ({
                emailId: row.id,
                emailName: row.name,
                emailCheckbox: <MDBInput label=" " value={checkedItems[row.id]} id={row.id} type="checkbox" onChange={handleCheckboxes}/>
            }))
            setData({
                columns: [
                    {
                        label: 'Email ID',
                        field: 'emailId'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Email name',
                        field: 'emailName'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Email checkbox',
                        field: 'emailCheckbox'
                    }
                ],
                rows: newRows
            });
        } catch(error) {
            setError(error.response);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            {error ? (
                <h1>{error.data.message}</h1>
            ) : (
                data ? (
                    <Fragment>
                        <h1>Event ID: {eventId}</h1>
                        <MDBDataTable data={data}/>
                    </Fragment>
                ) : (
                    <div className="text-center">
                        <MDBSpinner big/>
                    </div>
                )
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: post your components

Comment: Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: I updated my post with entire component. I'm not using TypeScript